# Finding the starting vertex for Dijkstra's algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, dijkstra, polygons

Imagine I am implementing Dijkstra's algorithm at a park. There are points and connections between those points; these specify valid paths the user can walk on (e.g. sidewalks).

Now imagine that the user is on the grass (i.e. not on a path) and wants to navigate to another location. The problem is not in Dijkstra's algorithm (which works fine), the problem is determining at which vertex to begin.

Here is a picture of the problem: (ignore the dotted lines for now)

[image]

**Black lines** show the edges in Dijkstra's algorithm; likewise, **purple circles** show the vertices. Sidewalks are in **gray**. The grass is, you guessed it, **green**. The user is located at the **red star**, and wants to get to the **orange X**.

If I naively look for the nearest vertex and use that as my starting point, the user is often directed to a suboptimal path, that involves walking further away from their destination at the start (i.e. the **red solid path**).

The **blue solid path** is the optimal path that my algorithm would ideally come up with.

Notes:

- Assume no paths cross over other paths.
- When navigating to a starting point, the user should never cross over a path (e.g. sidewalk).
- In the image above, the first line segment coming out of the star is created dynamically, simply to assist the user. The star is not a vertex in the graph (since the user can be anywhere inside the grass region). The line segment from the star to a vertex is simply being displayed so that the user knows how to get to the first valid vertex in the graph.

How can I implement this efficiently and correctly?

---

**Idea #1: Find the enclosing polygon**

If I find the smallest polygon which surrounds my starting point, I can now create new paths for Dijkstra's algorithm from the starting point (which will be added as a new vertex temporarily) to each of the vertices that make up the polygon. In the example above, the polygon has 6 sides, so this would mean creating 6 new paths to each of its vertices (i.e. the **blue dotted lines**). I would then be able to run Dijkstra's algorithm and it would easily determine that the blue solid line is the optimal path.

The problem with this method is in determining which vertices comprise the smallest polygon that surrounds my point. I cannot create new paths to each vertex in the graph, otherwise I will end up with the **red dotted lines** as well, which completely defeats the purpose of using Dijkstra's algorithm (I should not be allowed to cross over a sidewalk). Therefore, I must take care to only create paths to the vertices of the enclosing polygon. Is there an algorithm for this?

There is another complication with this solution: imagine the user now starts at the **purple lightning bolt**. It has no enclosing polygon, yet the algorithm should still work by connecting it to the 3 points at the top right. Again, once it is connected to those, running Dijkstra's is easy.
**Update:** the reason we want to connect to one of these 3 points and not walk around everything to reach the orange X directly is because we want to minimize the walking done on unpaved paths. (Note: This is only a constraint if you start outside a polygon. We don't care how long you walk on the grass if it is within a polygon).

If this is the correct solution, then please post its algorithm as an answer.

Otherwise, please post a better solution.

Comment: I don't really understand it. What are the constraints on valid paths? If you start outside, why can't you just walk on the outside to the target?

Comment: Also what is the desired runtime? O((n+m) * log n), like Dijkstra?

Comment: [Here's some wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_location) and [here's some SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10915791/how-can-a-find-a-face-containing-a-predefined-point-when-i-have-a-planar-graph-e).

Answer (score 1):

You can start off by running Dijkstra from the target to find its distance to all vertices.

Now let's consider the case where you start "inside" the graph on the grass. We want to find all vertices that we can reach via a straight line without crossing any edge. For that we can throw together all the line segments representing the edges and the line segments connecting the start point to every vertex and use a [sweep-line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm) to find whether the start-vertex lines intersect any edge.

Alternatively you can use any offline algorithm for [planar point location](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_location#Planar_case), those also work with a sweep line. I believe this is in the spirit of the more abstract algorithm proposed in the question in that it reports the polygon that surrounds the point.

Then we just need to find the vertex whose connection line to the start does not intersect any edge and the sum d(vertex, target) + d(vertex, start) is minimum.

The procedure when the vertex is outside the graph is somewhat underspecified, but I guess the exact same idea would work. Just keep in mind that there is the possibility to walk all around the graph to the target if it is on the border, like in your example.

This could probably be implemented in O((n+m) log m) per query. If you run an [all-pairs shortest path algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem#All-pairs_shortest_paths) as a preprocessing step and use an online point location algorithm, you can get logarithmic query time at the cost of the space necessary to store the information to speed up shortest path queries (quadratic if you just store all distance pairs).

I believe simple planar point location works just like the sweep line approaches, only with [persistent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure) BSTs to store all the sweepline states.

Comment: The key here is to minimize d(start,vertex) + d(vertex,end) over all vertices. You might emphasize that.

Comment: @bgschiller I wouldn't say that's the key. That's the trivial part. The key is to find the valid candidates for *vertex*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are a bothering with trying to find a starting vertex when you already have one. The point you (the user) are standing at is another vertex in of itself. So the real question now is to find the distance from your starting point to any other point in the enclosing polygon <s>graph</s>. And once you have that, you can simply run Dijkstra's or another shortest path algorithm method like A*, BFS, etc, to find the shortest path to your goal point.

On that note, I think you are better off implementing A* for this problem because a park involves things like trees, playgrounds, ponds (sometimes), etc. So you will need to use a shortest path algorithm that takes these into consideration, and A* is one algorithm that uses these factors to determine a path of shortest length.

**Finding distance from start to graph:**

The problem of finding the distance from your new vertex to other vertices can be done by only looking for points with the closest `x` or `y` coordinate to your start point. So this algorithm has to find points that form a sort of closure around the start point, i.e. a polygon of minimum area which contains the point. So as @Niklas B suggested, a planar point algorithm (with some modifications) might be able to accomplish this. I was looking at the sweep-line algorithm, but that only works for line segments so that will not work (still worth a shot, with modifications might be able to give the correct answer).

<s>You can also decide to implement this algorithm in stages, so first, find the points with the closest `y` coordinate to the current point (Both negative and positive y, so have to use absolute value), then among those points, you find the ones with the closest `x` coordinate to the current point and that should give you the set of points that form the polygon. Then these are the points you use to find the distance from your start to the graph.</s>

Comment: But how do you ensure that you don't cross a path while connecting the start point to one of the other vertices? Or in other words, what are the *edges* of your implcitly introduced new vertex?

Comment: That is what I mentioned, the problem doesn't lie in finding a vertex to start from, the real problem is how to determine the distance from your new vertex to all other points. And once you have this, you can then run your shortest path algorithm of choice to find a shortest path. You also don't need to worry about paths crossing because a good shortest path algorithm will choose the closest point. So if there are 2 paths crossing, the point on the closest path will be chosen before the later.

Comment: I disagree. Have a look at this graph: http://imgur.com/P1hz6Oy The cross is the start, the circle is the target. Using your proposed algorithm as I understand it, it will take the direct line that connects both, but that is not a valid path

Comment: @NiklasB. The graph you have shown only has one vertex on it, so indeed any algorithm that tries to find the shortest path from the x to the circle will either fail to find one or have to cross a path to find one. I have made my edit

Comment: Imagine all the corners being vertices (there are 3)